# Materialization of nouns by adjectives

Tags: semantics, nouns, adjectives, noun-phrases

I am not even an amateur in linguistics, especially semantics. I want to use this idea in *computational linguistics* that I am also new there. The idea is how to deal with nouns that become more concrete as we describe them using adjectives. For example, when we use `car` in a sentence, it is kind of abstract. But when we use `red car` or `fast red car` it is more concrete. I want to know the terminology about this idea and I also need some resources to read.

I want to try to use some ideas from semantics in the field of *word embeddings* and try to make NLP a little more intuitive. The basic idea here is *statistical semantics* and I want to see if I can apply it in this special case.

Comment: _Fast red car_ is more specific than _car_, but not more concrete. Are you sure you know what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

"Car" picks out a set, the set of cars. It is not particularly abstract, but it is large. "Red car" picks out the intersection of red things and cars, which is a subset of the set of cars. It is not less abstract, but it is a smaller set. So "red" can be said to *restrict* the reference of the nominal expression to which it attaches. It is an "interactive" adjective used here with a "restrictive" reading.